# Can't parse XML using simplexml_load_string in PHP

Tags: php, xml

How to pass the following message in PHP?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<response>
  <action>sendmessage</action>
  <data>
    <acceptreport>
      <statuscode>0</statuscode>
      <statusmessage>Message accepted for delivery</statusmessage>
      <messageid>8abbaf6c-3bdd-4fb7-9c49-282270bbb309</messageid>
      <originator>admin</originator>
      <recipient>233xxx</recipient>
      <messagetype>SMS:TEXT</messagetype>
      <messagedata>mdata</messagedata>
    </acceptreport>
  </data>
</response>
```

I have tried

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
var_dump($xml['data']);
```

and

```
var_dump($xml->attributes());
```

Nothing seems to be working. Any clue? What am I missing?

Comment: Is the lack of a `$` before `xml` in the initialization statement a typo, or is that what it looks like in your code?

Comment: That's exactly how it is

Comment: @rtuner In PHP, all variables being with `$`. To assign to a variable, the statement looks like `$xml = `.

Comment: @rtuner `var_dump` produced warning but you don't see it or what??

Comment: Oh just saw what you were saying @BrianWarshaw Thought you were actually referring to the 'xml' in the XML

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var_dump($xml->data->acceptreport->messagedata);
```

`$xml->attributes()` would be trying to get any attributes on the root node (`<response>`), and that node has no attributes.

Comment: Returns null for some reason :/